# Reading XML file using Dom4j package

Tags: xml, dom4j

I have XML file

```
<content>
     <std>
        <name>name1</name>
        <desc>desc1</desc>
        <sub>
           <sub1></sub1>
           <sub2></sub2>
        </sub>
     <std>
</content>
```

I am trying to read xml file Dom4j package

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document;
InputStream stream = "./somthing/asd.xml";
document = reader.read(stream);

Element contentsElement = document.getRootElement();
List<Element> Elemet = contentsElement.elements();

for(Element itemElement : sourceElements){
    itemElement.elementTextTrim("name");
    itemElement.elementTextTrim("desc");
    List<Elements> subList = itemElement.elements("sub");
    //Can't go into loop because subList.size() value is 0
    for(Element e2 : subList){
           e2.elementTextTrim("sub1");
    }

}
```

if read properly data but i want details about `<std>` tag 
so i will try comment lines but that can't work please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working fine for me .

```
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read("a.xml");
    Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();        
    List<Element> list =  rootElement.elements("std");

    for (Element element : list) {
        System.out.println(element.elementTextTrim("name"));
        List<Element> sublist =  element.elements("sub");
        for (Element element2 : sublist) {
            System.out.println(element2.elementTextTrim("sub1"));
            System.out.println(element2.elementTextTrim("sub2"));
        }

    }
```

For below a.xml :-

```
<content>
     <std>
        <name>name1</name>
        <desc>desc1</desc>
        <sub>
           <sub1>22</sub1>
           <sub2>223</sub2>
        </sub>
     </std>
</content>
```

Comment: yai...Bro..
you are right i am retry that code that is now work...
may be previous i do some mistake in code...

without Iterator it is easy to understand and easy to do work...
really thanks...:)